# Removing elements from an array: pop is not a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
thead = new Array();
alert(thead.length);
thead = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
alert(thead.length);


thead.pop();
alert(thead.length);
```

`document.getElementsByTagName("th")` returns an array of elements, so `thead` variable should be an array, if so, then why it gives me the error "thead.pop() is not a function"?

Comment: Are you trying to remove from the DOM, or just from the list? If you actually want it removed from the DOM, do this... `var last = thead[thead.length - 1]; last.parentNode.removeChild(last);` The element will be removed from the DOM, as well as the `thead` list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)) does not return an `Array`, it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList). As said by the linked `NodeList` docs:

> NodeList are used very much like arrays and it would be tempting to use Array.prototype methods on them. This is, however, impossible.

There are some `Array` like things you can do with a `NodeList`, and you can even `.apply` some `Array.prototype` methods to them, but you should read the docs to avoid the "gotchas", especially where problems with the `NodeList` being "live" could bite you.

Comment: Lol Ok I can stop editing it now. Just saying that static nodelists can be treated like arrays without much problems whereas live nodelists cannot.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was adding some clarification and documentation as you were editing.

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [`DOM 2 NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-536297177), not an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` object, which has no `pop` function.

Try `alert(Array.isArray(thead))`, and you'll see that it returns false